# how to finalize generating a signed SDK

Tags: android, sdk, signed, generate

When trying to generate a signed SDK, I receive an error message:

" Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. "

As instructed, I started the SDK Manager, but I do not find where I can accept the SDK license agreements or install missing components. I see that some components can be updated, but I fail to find how to do that.

My Android studio 4.1.2 runs under Windows 10 home 64bit. To be able to generate signed SDK, I chose Android 9.0 (Pie) API level 28

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the licences before building.

According to [Android SDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) you can use the following command depending on the sdkmanager location: Docs on --licenses option seems to be missing though.

> %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses